# Web development effects

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am relatively new to web development. I was surfing around www.trello.com and was curious as to how to achieve their list effects. Please take a look at this [video](http://youtu.be/VC4zUeAuT-k) for more details.

Is this AJAX? If so, how can I do this with JQuery ?

Are there any articles/tutorials on how to create the same effects ? These would be greatly appreciated !

I want to build a Rails 3.2 web app that uses these similar effects

Comment: not when everything is minimized -.-

Comment: True, however with Firebug or Web Inspector you'll be able to see everything that is rendered and watch in real-time as you drag and drop a task that they add a `ui-sortable-helper` class to the DIV which applies a 3 deg rotation via CSS... you can do the same with vanilla JS or use the drag&drop/sortable options in jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 1):

This is not ajax related (though it may use some ajax in the background for something else). JQuery has drag and drop effects: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ - look into their documentation and do some tutorial reading! Good luck! :)

There are numerous plugins and other things: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/04/jquery-drag-drop-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the development stack of Trello is fully disclosed on their blog:

http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/

Its a combination of: CoffeeScript, Backbone.js, HTML5 pushState, Mustache, CloudFront CDN, AJAX, WebSockets, Socket.io (modified), node.js, HAProxy, Redis, MongoDB